# How to tune video's audio speed?

Tags: video

I have a video which have audio falling behind the video for some secs, how can I convert it to proper time?

It's xp. And I think it always delayed by the same amount of time. I use Windows media player classic to tune to the audio playback to -60ms and I feel just fine. I am looking for a method to adjust it for convenience.

It's avi file.

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: Is that audio always delayed by the same amount of time?

Answer (score 1):

If you merely want to plat the video for yourself, not fix it for distribution, most player softwares include a function to delay audio by a variable duration (positive or negative). In VLC, for instance, this is achieved with the <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> buttons by default, in 50 ms increments.

For a permanent fix, you would in the best case scenario just have to re-mux the video and audio from you original file into a new container, supplying time scaling and offsets. This will at least work for mkv container, not sure about others if you insist on them.

In the worst case scenario, you would have to reencode the audio (or the video if you prefer for some reason) to fit together. Most encoding frontends support this, or they can encode the output of a decoder that supports the changes.

Comment: You can basically remux any container, but it would be good to know which one is used here to give more more concrete info.

Comment: Yes, you can remux form any container to any other container, provided the track formats are somehow "supported" by the container. I generally use mkv, which as I understand it is slightly smarter than many other containers. Audio scaling and offset is supported by mkv. I don't truly know if they are supported by other common containers. The solution of remuxing will not work if there is a requirement for the result to be in a container that does not support audio scaling and offset.